# Join performance in AWS Athena improvement

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, sqlperformance

I'm trying to join 2 tables in Athena where the date in the second table has to be between two dates in the first table, but they take too long. Inverting the order of the tables improved the performance, but somehow the performance is different when I do a RIGHT JOIN.

1. Is there any other way to make this join quicker? Does it make sense to keep the CROSS JOIN for all the data?
2. How can this behaviour be explained?
   I thought A LEFT JOIN B = B RIGHT JOIN A. But execution times don't point to that

I'm using a subset of the data. The total size of car_locations is 307184 and app_opening 3024250.

car_locations looks like this and has 16062 rows for the analysis subset:
[image]

app_opening looks like this and has 147747 rows for the analysis subset:

[image]

This join takes in average 1 min to execute:

```
SELECT
    sk_app_openingevent,
    eventdatetime_local,
    device_id,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    COUNT(sk_app_openingevent) AS available_fleet_size,
    MIN(GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE(latitude, longitude, gps_latitude, gps_longitude))AS closest_car_km
FROM app_opening
LEFT JOIN car_locations ON eventdatetime_local BETWEEN from_datetime_local AND to_datetime_local
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

Changing LEFT to RIGHT takes it down to 45 sec.

However, swapping the order of the tables makes it run in 20-25 sec:

```
SELECT
    sk_app_openingevent,
    eventdatetime_local,
    device_id,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    COUNT(sk_app_openingevent) AS available_fleet_size,
    MIN(GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE(latitude, longitude, gps_latitude, gps_longitude)) AS closest_car_km
FROM car_locations
LEFT JOIN app_opening ON eventdatetime_local BETWEEN from_datetime_local AND to_datetime_local
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

But again changing LEFT to RIGHT makes it run in somehow worse than the first join, at 6 mins.

Lastly, this CROSS JOIN is runs at about 20-22 sec:

```
SELECT
    sk_app_openingevent,
    eventdatetime_local,
    device_id,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    COUNT(sk_app_openingevent) AS available_fleet_size,
    MIN(GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE(latitude, longitude, gps_latitude, gps_longitude)) AS closest_car_km
FROM car_locations
CROSS JOIN app_opening 
WHERE eventdatetime_local BETWEEN from_datetime_local AND to_datetime_local
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

**Edit:**

Here's a table with runtimes:

| runtime (secs) | cl inner app | cl left app | cl cross app | cl right app | app inner cl | app left cl | app cross cl | app right cl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| run 1 | 24 | 21 | 23 | 299 | 40 | 82 | 41 | 42 |
| run 2 | 22 | 22 | 21 | 373 | 42 | 80 | 43 | 42 |
| run 3 | 21 | 20 | 22 | 333 | 41 | 76 | 41 | 42 |
| run 4 | 22 | 21 | 21 | 338 | 46 | 79 | 40 | 40 |
| run 5 | 21 | 21 | 20 | 364 | 41 | 76 | 41 | 40 |

Comment: Have you tried looking into `explain`?

Comment: _"I thought A LEFT JOIN B = B RIGHT JOIN A. But execution times don't point to that"_ - runtime can be used as (dis) prove/point of this equality. Only resulting set.

Comment: Also you have not change left to right after swapping tables - `FROM app_opening LEFT JOIN car_locations` an `FROM car_locations LEFT JOIN app_opening`

Comment: I did test LEFT to RIGHT when I tested it and got the runtimes I mention, I just didn't post the code here, as it's just that change.
I'm not sure I understand what you mean it can be used to disprove equality. Isn't it doing precisely that now? 2 joins that should have the same runtime have consistently different runtimes

Comment: I've just looked into `explain` for the best cases. Whenever I put FROM car_locations JOIN app_opening the first 2 stages run in parallel. Regardless of LEFT, RIGHT or CROSS join.
This also means that: car_locations CROSS JOIN app_openingsruns in approximately half the time as app_opening CROSS JOIN car_locations. Shouldn't this be symmetrical?

Comment: _" I'm not sure I understand what you mean it can be used to disprove equality. Isn't it doing precisely that now? "_ - `A LEFT JOIN B = B RIGHT JOIN A` means that they will have the same result set, not that the implementation will have the same runtime which can be affected by multiple things like how the data is partitioned for example.